# Plumber help on exposing API

Tags: r, api, plumber

Hello I am new to R and so to Plumber. I would like to get help in how to expose this as an API using the `plumber` package. Currently I got the following error:

```
<simpleError in UseMethod("xml_find_all"): no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "function">
```

The code:

```
**library(dplyr)
library(Rcrawler)
library(readr)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)
library(plumber)
#* @param filesin:string
#* @param sp:numeric
#* @param cd:numeric
#* @param tk:string
#* @post /suggest
suggest<-function(filesin,sp,cd,tk)
{
  
  sp<- as.numeric(sp)
  
  cd<- as.numeric(cd)
    
  files <- list.files(filesin, pattern=".txt", all.files = TRUE, full.names = TRUE) 
  
  a<-1
  
  metaVetor <- c()
  
  while (a <= length(files))
  {  
    data <- read_html(files[a])
    ap <- data %>% html_elements("meta") 
    ap<- as.character(ap)
    metaVetor<- append(metaVetor, ap)   
    a = a+1
  }
  
  selDesc <- grep(pattern = "description", x = metaVetor)
  selDate <- grep(pattern = "creation_date", x = metaVetor)
  selModified <- grep(pattern = "modified", x = metaVetor)
  selKey <- grep(pattern = "keywords", x = metaVetor)
  selTitle <- grep(pattern = "title", x = metaVetor)
  
  Indexes <- c(selDesc,selDate,selModified,selKey,selTitle)
  
  metasInteresse <- c()
  
  a<-1
  
  while(a<= length(Indexes))
  {
    metasInteresse<- append(metasInteresse, metaVetor[Indexes[a]])
    a = a + 1
  }
  
  selPar <- data %>% html_elements("p") %>% html_text
  
  metasInteresse<- append(metasInteresse, selPar)
  
  metasInteresse <- gsub('\\|<|>|description|content|<meta|property|title|-|"|=|:|\n|\\|!| ', ",", metasInteresse)
  
  stopWords <- c("da","de","do","a","no","que","com","","e","se","as","o","na","os","name","para","em","og")
  
  vTest<- strsplit(metasInteresse,',')
  
  
  a<-1
  j<-1
  st<-1
  
  while(a<= length(vTest))
  {
    while(st<= length(stopWords))
    {
      if(vTest[[a]][j] == stopWords[st])
      {
        vTest[[a]][j] <- vTest[[a]][j+2]
        
        j<- j+2
        
      } 
      else
      {
        
        j<- j+1
        
      }
      
      st<- st+1     
      
    }
    
    a<- a+1
  }
  
  
  return(vTest)
  
}**
```

Comment: When exactly do you get the error? How are you testing the function? I'm guessing the error is coming from `selPar <- data %>% html_elements("p") %>% html_text` which would happen if `files` is empty since that means `data` would never be created in your script and `data` is a built in function in R. Try debugging the script by adding in `return("test")` early in the function to make sure that works and keep moving that so you can find where the error occurs.

Comment: Hello, i got this error when i call the api with swagger, i runned the code as an local script and it worked properly but when i exposed the api i got this problem...i would like to return a json

Comment: Are you actually passing values to the "filesin" parameter? Are you passing full paths or relative paths? My guess is that the `list.files` command it not matching anything. It's hard to say for sure since the problem isn't [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) since we can't run it to test it ourselves.

Comment: yes i am passing it, maybe it is about permissions..

Comment: i alson cannot access it by brownser..

Comment: does plumber really work or it is one local issue?

Comment: ok at least here this package did not work i had to use httpuv instead ;-(